# Chrome window resizing issue

Tags: google-chrome, resize, window

I want to resize my browser window, but my code doesn't work for Chrome.
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertClick(event, formElem)
{
     window.resizeTo(600, 600);
}   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's an omitted feature.

The bug report [Issue 2091: window.resizeTo() doesn't have any effect](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2091) on the Chromium project has more information and plenty of discussion on the matter.

Comment: Is there any other way to resize Chrome window?

Comment: According to that link, they've removed all ways to resize a tabbed window. Who knows why. Popups, on the other hand, is a different matter.

Comment: @J.Steen: What do you mean by *who knows why*? It's pretty easy to understand the rationale behind this. Window resizing is pretty obnoxious anyway. When a window is tabbed this means that this would affect all other tabs as well. A popup on the other hand is a *lone wolf* that's not related to other tabs. I do understand that there are situations when one would want to resize a window, but this security/usability feature is pretty reasonable and welcomed.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik My *who knows why?* was more a comment on the fact that such changes are usually never explained publicly. I like your rationale, however, and the conclusion sounds good. =)